# windows in a loop and pass a unique parameter to each window.open when event happen onload

Tags: javascript, html, onload, window.open

How to open several tens of windows in a loop and pass a unique parameter to each window and add html code? In the example, the code does not work, only in one window page added the word three times "PAGE NAME:"

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

var  winName = 'winname_i'+i;
var newWin = window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', winName, 'width=400, height=400');
        console.log("winName="+winName);

        newWin.onload = function(winName) {
                        console.log("function-winName="+winName);

                      var div = newWin.document.createElement('div'),
                          body = newWin.document.body;
                          div.innerHTML = 'PAGE NAME:! '+ winName;
                          div.style.fontSize = '40px';
                          body.insertBefore(div, body.firstChild);


                    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Inspite of using onload you can try using onchange. Hope that helps.